# How To display title, image etc. from product meta field of type product?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I'm trying to display the products I saved in a meta field on my product detail page like this:

```
<h2>Cross Selling goes here</h2>
  {{ product.metafields.custom.styled_with }}
```

... but all I get it is:

`["GID://SHOPIFY/PRODUCT/7978216456473","GID://SHOPIFY/PRODUCT/7978217177369","GID://SHOPIFY/PRODUCT/7978217537817","GID://SHOPIFY/PRODUCT/7978217570585"]`

How can I render these products? I want to access the product title, image etc.
I'm using the Dawn Theme.

Do I need to run a query or something?

Thanks in advance!

I tried this line of code

{{ product.metafields.custom.styled_with }}

and I expected that I would have access to the product information directly (product title etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding `.value`

```
{% for recommended_product in product.metafields.custom.styled_with.value %}
    {{ recommended_product.title }}
  {% endfor %}
```